# Could not find cache store adapter for redis_cache_store (cannot load such file -- active_support/cache/redis_cache_store)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to use redis as cache on heroku, following this guide: https://blog.heroku.com/rails-database-optimization

I added redis and hiredis to the gemfile, added `config.cache_store = :redis_cache_store, { url: ENV['REDIS_URL'] }` to production.rb.

I get this error:

```
Could not find cache store adapter for redis_cache_store (cannot load such file -- active_support/cache/redis_cache_store)
```

I'm using rails 5.1.4